# Two activities one along with second diverted from one to second getting following issue with setting background in activity_display_message.xml

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

first activity activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/download"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button1"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

second activity activity_display_message.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/ool"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.startanotheractivity.DisplayMessageActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So , when i click on the button present inside activity_main.xml 
the background set to the second activity didn't get dispalyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to ask?

Do you want to replace the first activity with second? Or add the second activity as a component to the first activity? If yes , then you should just inflate the second activity[component] in the first activity dynamically, as follows:

Inflate second activity->add to->First activity's linear layout/or whichever layout

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open activity_display_message from your activity_main, you need to use startActivity(intent) on button click.

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
})
```